# php's include done a space in my html layout

Tags: php, html, layout

I have this:

```
<div id="results">
    <?php include 'server.php'; ?>
</div>
```

which done a space in my html layout.

[image: include problem]

Server.php looks like:

```
<?php
//php processing...

//first echo:
echo '<h1>Serveur : '.$hostname.'</h1>';

//others echo...
?>
```

Why this space ? A solution ?

Comment: I believe the added space is really just a part of the H1 element. This is easy to test, since you're debugging in Chrome -- just delete that empty space in the "Elements" view and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: RightClick -> Inspect Element, see where the space is coming from

Comment: It was the include. Encoding problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Verify that the file server.php isn't in UTF-8 with BOM, and try removing the closing tag, ie :

```
  <?php
  //php processing...

  //first echo:
  echo '<h1>Serveur : '.$hostname.'</h1>';

  //others echo...
```